# compilation error with template functions inline

Tags: c++, templates

I have a simple template function that uses two parameters:

```
template<typename To, typename From>To* asSomething( Common *item)
{
    From  * tdnItem = downcast( item, From );
    To    * someClass = NULL;

    if( tdnItem != NULL ) 
    {
        someClass = downcast( tdnItem->gloo(), To );
    }

    return someClass;
}
```

Later, I call this helper method in another inline method:

```
return asSomething<ToFoo, FromFoo>(item);
```

However, I get a weird compilation error in Visual Studio:

```
error C2065: 'FromTmeta' : undeclared identifier
see reference to function template instantiation 'To *asSomething<ToFoo,FromFoo>(Common * *)' being compiled
with
[
    To=ToFoo
]
error C2065: 'ToTmeta' : undeclared identifier
```

The function declaration looks correct to me, what's the issue here?

Comment: Which line(s) does the error point to?

Comment: I can't see the `FromTmeta` symbol that the compiler is complaining about.  Is it elsewhere, or did you rename it in your example code?

Comment: @immibis The first error points to the 'From  * tdnItem' declaration. The second one is on the asSomething(...) call.

Comment: I suspect `downcast` is a macro. macros and template parameters don't work well if you are using the arguments to concatenate other things to the type.

Comment: yes, downcast(...) is a macro, you might be right, let me check.

Comment: @Drew Dormann I think they may be internal code from the macro R Sahu mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `downcast` is a pre-processor macro. Pre-processor macros and template parameters don't work well if you are using the arguments to concatenate other things to the type.

Replace

```
From  * tdnItem = downcast( item, From );
```

by

```
From  * tdnItem = dynamic_cast<From*>(item);
```

and

```
someClass = downcast( tdnItem->gloo(), To );
```

by

```
someClass = dynamic_cast<To*>( tdnItem->gloo());
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. While I can't use this exact solution, I can replace the macro with something else.